# Problem with lazy loading in Angular and AOT compilation

Tags: angular, typescript, module, lazy-loading

Whenever I try to compile my Angular 8 Ionic 5 App using the AOT compiler option, I get the following error:

```
ERROR in Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'loadChildren')
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.
```

There are 3 user types in my App. The app works just fine when compiling without AOT. The user type is not known until the user attempts the login process.

The modules are located in these paths inside the project:

- src/app/myapp/home-end-user
- src/app/myapp/home-company-user
- src/app/myapp/home-agent-user

The following function will redirect to a different component based on the user type that logs in:

```
export function configHomeRoutes(authService: AuthService) {
    let route: Routes;

    if (authService.currentRol.user_type === 'end_user') {
        route = [{
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () => import('../home-end-user/home-end-user.module').then(m => m.HomeEndUserPageModule),
        }];
    } else if (authService.currentRol.user_type === 'agent_user') {
        route = [{
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () => import('../home-agent-user/home-agent-user.module').then(m => m.HomeAgentUserPageModule),
        }];
    } else if (authService.currentRol.user_type === 'company_user') {
        route = [{
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () => import('../home-company-user/home-company-user.module').then(m => m.HomeCompanyUserPageModule),
        }];
    }

    return route;
}
```

Finally, this is the tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

I have tried replacing the arrow function imports for string imports, but I always get an error that the app is unable to find the module needed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that as far as I remember the routes definition **must not** be dynamic during the runtime. You can define the routes during the build time but not the runtime.